# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error Visual Studios 2012

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2012

When i create a new asp.net 3.5 web site in Visual Studio and just run it i get the above error from the IIS express that runs through VS..

Ive trawled the web looking for a solution, would anyone know why this has started happening?

Also my old projects run fine still! its just new ones i create!!

Some of my recent projects are .net 4.5/4.0.

thanks
Neil

Comment: Weird. Is this by chance a blank MVC application?

Comment: the last project i done was an MVC app and it worked.  But now any ASP.net apps i create dont work for some reason!! lol

Answer (score 0):

An internal server error means just that - something went wrong on the server side of the request. It could be almost anything. Check your event logs (Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application) to find the actual exception message. It will be listed as an error from ASP.NET.

Comment: ok. there was loads of errors in there saying this:

The Diagnostic Service Host service failed to start due to the following error: 
A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration.

Any idea?  Id love to know how to done this :)

Comment: @niallNoigeallach I'm not sure, but at least now you have an error message you can stick into Google.